# How can I not cache IPython variables?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When you first run the IPython block with a variable with a dictionary, for example:

```
In[7]: test_dict = {'key_1': 1.8529757571664867,
                    'key_2': 1.551270403313663,
                    'key_3': 0.8213399558579995}
```

and function:

```
In[8]: def rename_keys(inp_dict, add):
           for k, v in sorted(inp_dict.items()):
               inp_dict[k + add] = inp_dict.pop(k)
           return inp_dict

In[9]: rename_keys(test_dict, '_W')
```

IPython will print the expected result:

```
Out[9]: {'key_1_W': 1.8529757571664867,
         'key_2_W': 1.551270403313663,
         'key_3_W': 0.8213399558579995}
```

But, for example, if I wanted to change the ending from "_W" to "_K", then when I change and restart the block, I get the old variable with the already changed end + new ending:

```
In[10]: rename_keys(test_dict, '_K')

Out[10]: {'key_1_W_K': 1.8529757571664867,
          'key_2_W_K': 1.551270403313663,
          'key_3_W_K': 0.8213399558579995}
```

How to make a notepad run code from scratch?

> Of course, it is logical and obvious that subsequent calls mean an already changed object, but can I make it so that when I change it in `In [9]` I have the output `Out [9]`?

Answer (score 2):

Let rename_keys return a new object, rather than changing the old one:

```
def rename_keys(inp_dict, add):
    return {key + add: value for key, value in inp_dict.items()}
```

Then use it like

```
renamed = rename_keys(test_dict, '_W')
```

Now `test_dict` will still contain the original keys.

Answer (score 2):

This is just how iPython works. The cells execute in the order you run them - not in the order in the document. You can call `cell->Run All Above` if you want to rerun from scratch.

The philosophy here is about being able to do quick debugging / prototyping, rather than writing a sequential code.